# In Django-Rest-Framework POST call which updates manytomany field works with JSON but not with form-data

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, request, postman, multipartform-data

I want to run a POST call that creates a "group". Assume that "persons" will all be existent. Even if they aren't, an error is not a problem.

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    persons = models.ManyToManyField(to=Person, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=file_location, null=True, blank=True)

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    persons = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Person.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

If I send a JSON like

```
{
    "title": "Drama Club",
    "persons": [1,2,3]
}
```

it will work. But since I cannot upload a file, I use FORM-DATA.

```
title: Drama Club
persons: [1,2,3]
file: <whatever the format is>
```

Now here comes the problem. IT DOES NOT WORK. It returns this error

```
{
    "persons": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
    ]
}
```

Even if I remove everything else, and just send `persons: [1,2,3]` as form-data, it returns the same error.
I really cannot understand this behavior. (I am using POSTMAN to check this)

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that form-data does not take an array. So, instead of
`persons : [1,2,3]`
I will have to send

```
persons : 1
persons : 2
persons : 3
```

Django-rest-framework will do the rest. 
Putting this answer here, because it took me a very long time to figure it out.

---

(if there is a way to send an array in form-data, without special parsing on the backend, I would love to know)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload a file and send the JSON payload as well, take a look at [DRF MultipartParser](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser)

Comment: The api can already receive JSON, as long as file is not there. The problem was that multiple "persons" could not be sent as an array.